# Possibly over there

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix is possible,
>   My old suffix is over there,
>   My infix is whatever you want,
>   And my whole might be really grand.

What am I?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are a

> Canyon

My prefix is possible,

> Can

My old suffix is over there,

> Yon, like over yonder, which is a word not used anymore.

My infix is whatever you want,

> Any

And my whole might be really grand

> Canyon or The Grand Canyon.

Comment: Well, that was fast. What gave it away?

Comment: The "old" suffix is also probably referring to that the word being referred to is not in common use anymore (it's kinda completely out of usage), and is a rather "old" word in that sense.